# Searching two excel columns for occurrence of two strings together

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I'm looking for a way to count the number of times two cells appear side by side in Excel - like intersections. Sometimes in my data (of about 550 records) A Road will appear next to B Road, which is a count of 1. If it occurs again, later in the data the count would be 2. But if B Road appears in the first column and A Road appears in the second column, I can't find a way to make that number 3 in the count.

I've tried concatenating the data, but I need to be able to write this formula without inserting specific criteria (like searching for A Road) because it would be easier in that case to do this manually. Does anyone know if there's a formula for find the occurrence of the same two variables between two columns without specific criteria?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your intent, then try this array formula : =SUM(IF(EXACT(B$2:B3&C$2:C3,B3&C3),1,""))+SUM(IF(EXACT(B$2:B3&C$2:C3,C3&B3),1,"")).The second sum formula  accounts for any reverse order of adjacent street occurrences.Then copy down the column as needed. Enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: @Anne: B and C are are the assumed columns holding the street names ; this was entirely random on my part.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of values in the two columns were important (i.e. A Road followed by B Road is *different* than B Road followed by A Road), then a simple pivot table would provide the counts you need. You would just put Col M on the rows, Col N on the columns and the count of any field as the value.

But the OP has said that A Road followed by B Road should be counted in the same total as B Road followed by A Road. Let's modify the concatenation in Col O to become `=IF(M2<N2,CONCAT(M2," & ",N2),CONCAT(N2," & ",M2))`. That provides a canonical form of each combination regardless of order. Having done that, then it is again an easy matter to create a pivot table that shows all the required counts -- just put the concatenated value on the rows and the count as the value.